# How automatically use the most recent version of a package?

Tags: .net, nuget

We are using custom framework.dlls that we want to use as nuGet packages within our development team.

When we e.g. deploy our framework.dll as framework.1.0.nupkg and want to upgrade the framework, is there a way to set in our projects to use the highest version or will nuget do that already?
I am not sure, since in the packages.config  is a fixed version.

Would Nuget update when we deployed a new 1.0 version or how to set version="$highest"?

Answer (score 0):

if you use the same package ID aka MyFramework then when a new version of the dll is deploy and you update through NuGet we handle removing the old reference and adding the new one for you.

Comment: I am looking for a "feature" like framework_backend.dll is updated by team_A and team_B is using the resulting nupak then the framework must be updated automatically or by force since team_B might not know that the framework is updated... and therefore would not go to the package tool to manually click update

Comment: I think the solution here is better communication between teams :)

Comment: In an ideal world we would not have to remind team-members to add their changes to SVN manually ;-) ... At least an annoying popup to update would help in our case ...

Comment: You could script calls to Update-Package (possibly using -Safe), however I'm with Matthew - upgrading should really be a conscious decision and should be tested that it hasn't introduced any issues!

Comment: Well worst case You can do what @Danny suggested and script update-package for only your framework package in the build process. But also sounds like you need some new devs :)